# If any lines in 2 variable arrays match

Tags: arrays, perl, variables, match

Still very very new to Perl so forgive me if this seems totally basic but I've been Googling around for quite some time. I have 2 variables; both have multiple IP addresses on each line.

Variable $a

```
111.11.11.11
333.33.33.33
111.11.11.11
```

Variable $b

```
222.22.22.22
111.11.11.11
222.22.22.22
```

I want to make an if statement of "If any of the ips in these 2 variables match, then proceed". For example:

```
print "What is the website that is offline or displaying an error?";
my $host = readline(*STDIN);
chomp ($host);

# perform the ping
if( $p->ping($host,$timeout) )
{
    #Host replied! Time to check which IP it is resolving to.
    my $hostips = Net::DNS::Nslookup->get_ips("$host");
    $hostips =~ s/$host.//g;;
}
    #We have a list of IPs, now we need to make sure that IP resolves to this server.
    #This is where the 2nd if statement begins (making sure one of the ips in both arrays match).




else
{
        print "".$host." is not pinging at this time. There is a problem with DNS\n";
}
$p->close();
```

I must keep in mind that this is an if statement within an if statement (which will continue into many more if statements)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a hash to quickly check there is a common IP in two arrays:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @array1 = qw( 111.11.11.11
                 333.33.33.33
                 111.11.11.11
              );
my @array2 = qw( 222.22.22.22
                 111.11.11.12
                 222.22.22.22
              );

my %match;
undef @match{@array1};

my $matches;
for my $ip (@array2) {
    $matches = 1, last if exists $match{$ip};
}

print $matches ? 'Matches' : "Doesn't match", "\n";
```

Comment: This definitely works! The problem is, I am very new to perl and I am having a bit of trouble understanding it/using it how I like. Basically, if I find a match I want to execute more code. If I don't find a match I want to execute a different set of code.

So instead of print, I want something like.

If matches: Do all this code

If not matches: do all this other code

Comment: Got it :) Perl is fun!
    if ($matches){
      print "This domain does point to this server!", "\n";
   #Apache begins
     }else{
      print "This domain does not point to this server!", "\n";
     }

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this to work out if an IP address appears in both of your lists.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use List::MoreUtils 'uniq';

my @array1 = qw( 111.11.11.11
                 333.33.33.33
                 111.11.11.11
              );
my @array2 = qw( 222.22.22.22
                 111.11.11.11
                 222.22.22.22
              );

# Remove duplicates from each array
@array1 = uniq @array1;
@array2 = uniq @array2;

my %element;

# Count occurances
$element{$_}++ for @array1, @array2;

# Keys with the value 2 appear in both array
say $_ for grep { $element{$_} == 2 } keys %element;
```